# Executing git related commands in shell script under git repository

Tags: git, bash, shell

Imaging I have two different branches:

- branch1
- branch2

Now I have written a shell script in branch `branch1` named `sync.sh` (Note that `sync.sh` is added and committed to that branch) which has following statements:

```
git checkout branch2
#Now perform some operations on branch2 like pull, commit something and push
git checkout branch1
#Again perform some operations on branch1
```

Now my question is will this work ? Because when it is switched to `branch2`, there will be no script in the filesystem on it. So will it execute properly? On my attempt, it seems to be working. But can this thing be relied upon ?

Comment: It might be best to just copy to a temp and execute that. As @EtanReisner points out what you're doing will work in all the common circumstances, but I think running from a temp will be reliable under all but the most convoluted imaginable in-script spelling/residence dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the script doesn't need to re-execute itself or refer to itself from disk then yes you can count on this.

The script will already be running. The running shell has the file open and will continue to read from it until the script finishes.

Comment: You can even copy from a process's `/proc/$pid/fd'`s.